# Not displaying model information

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model

I am new to ember and cannot seem to figure out why my list will not display. Here is the code where I create the model on the route page:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return ['Ford', 'tesla','lexus'];
    }
});
```

and this is my template page

```
 <h1>Cars</h1>
<ul>
    {{#each car in model}}
        <li>{{car}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But for some reason no information is being displayed. Does anybody notice something I am not seeing? Thanks in advance!

```
    <p>
    <strong>authors: </strong>
        {{#each authors}}
            {{this}},
        {{/each}}
</p>
<h4>Comments</h4>
<ul>
    {{#each comments as comment}}
        <li><strong>{{name}}</strong> - {{comment}}</li>

    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
action:{
    sayHello: function(){
        alert('Hello')
    },
    toggleBody: function(){
        this.toggleProperty('isShowingBody');
    },
    submitAction: function(){
        alert(this.get('name'));
        alert(this.get('comment'));
    }
},

title: 'My Bliog Post',
body: 'My body of work is endless i tell you',
authors: ['william','robert','michelle'],
created: new Date(),
comments: [
    {
        name: 'Evan',
        comment: 'Hey what is new '
    },{
        name: 'Evan',
        comment: 'Hey ith you'
    },{
        name: 'Evan',
        comment: 'Hey what is n'
    }
]
```

});

Comment: Follow ember guides. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/ I think you are following syntax which is used in older version of ember. thats deprecated and removed now

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your each statement:

```
{{#each model as |car|}}
 {{car}}
{{/each}}
```

for example : https://ember-twiddle.com/ed1ea81eb660a3ea2088c535961f2e2f?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Comment: That helped with that.. But I have other instances similar that have the same issue. I will revise my original post

Comment: as @kumkanillam said in comments, the syntax used is wrong in your each statement, you need to add pipes, I have update the twiddle with your template update. [updated example](https://ember-twiddle.com/ed1ea81eb660a3ea2088c535961f2e2f?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) as well you have a typo error in your controller : action => actionS